# How many are LSTM Gates?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

It is very confusing while googling for LSTM gates , I find that some references and articles say that they are three gates: input , forget and output gates , While others say that they are four gates : learn , forget , remember, and use gate ?

So, what is the right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four gates: input modulation gate, input gate, forget gate and output gate, representing four sets of parameters.

We can see that there are four sets of parameters(8 matrices) colored in blue in the below graph of LSTM where f stands for the forget gate, g and i the add gate, o the output gate. Since the add gate needs two sets of parameters we can combine them as just one gate.

[image]

Reference:
Speech and Language Processing

Answer (score 0):

Long Short Term Memory networks – usually just called “LSTMs” – are a special kind of RNN, capable of learning long-term dependencies. So there are different types of LSTMs, LSTMs have chain-like structure like RNN, but the repeating module has a different structure. Instead of having a single neural network layer, there are four, interacting in a very special way. However, there are many variants of LSTMS.

Ref: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/